# Syntax error in For loop because of searching for a ":" in Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

This is probably a really easy fix but I don't know how to do it. I'm using Python.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as beauty
import cloudscraper


scraper = cloudscraper.create_scraper(delay=10, browser='chrome') #
url = ""

info = scraper.get(url).text
soup = beauty(info, "html.parser")
description = soup.find_all('meta', property_ = 'og:title')

for og:title in description:
    print(og:title.text)
```

I just want to search for og:title in description but the : in og:title keeps giving me a syntax error. I tried quotation marks but that didn't work. I had the same problem with a - sign in another thing I was searching for. How do I make python treat them as just text? Sorry for bad question this is my first day ever coding

Comment: Could you please edit your question adding the complete code?

Comment: `for og:title in description:` You can't use `:` in a variable name. Call it something else, like `og_title`.

Comment: The thing that goes between `for` and `in` is just a variable name of your choice.  The name has no effect on what the loop does - but it does have to be a valid variable name (which does not include colons).

Comment: Use: `for item in description: print(item.text)`. A Python variable can't contain `:` or `-` (only `_`, letters and digits).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour]. I've never used BeautifulSoup myself, but it looks like `soup.find_all()` gets the data you're looking for, but you think the variable name you use for that data matters, which it doesn't, and that variable name is invalid. Try using `og_title` like Nick said and see what happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> for og:title in description:
>     print(og:title.text)
> ```

That's not valid python code.
Identifiers should contain alphanumeric
and `_` underscore characters.
Avoid putting `:` colon in an identifier.

Spell it this way and you should be fine:

```
for og_title in description:
    print(og_title.text)
```